# Copying .ttf font file onto Raspberry Pi4

Tags: pi-4

How can I copy a font file (Garamond.ttf) from a USB stick onto a Pi4?  I don't know which of the several directories to try to put it in, usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont is one that I've tried, but each time I drag and drop the file I'm told

> The file operation was completed with errors.  Data transferred 193KiB (100%).
>
> Error opening file /usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefontGARA.TTF  Permission denied.

But the file hasn't been copied.  (LibreOffice currently makes existing documents 50% longer with its version of Garamond using ostensibly the same font size.)

Answer (score 2):

You need superuser privileges to write to most `/usr/share` directories. From the command line try:

```
sudo cp wherever/freefontGARA.TTF /usr/share/fonts/truetype/
```

Answer (score 1):

Just drag-n-drop it to the `/home/pi/.fonts/` folder. If the folder does not exist, create it.
`/usr/share/fonts` is protected so the pi user can't edit it.
You can open an 'admin' file manager by running in the terminal: `sudo pcmanfm`. I use this trick all the time.